# Vertex insertions as functionals

Tags: string-theory

In lecture notes on string theory by David Tong (available for free here http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/string.html) a brief explanation of the vertex operator for tachyon is given. The main points are:

1. Because it has to be diffeomorphism-invariant, it is a result of an integration of some quantity over the world-sheet.
2. Because it is conformal-invariant, the quantity has to correspond to the primary operator with weight $(+1, +1)$ in order to compensate the $d^2z$ measure
3. Because tachyon is the vacuum of the string, it has to correspond to the highest-weight state of the Verma module. This is fulfilled if

$$ L_n \left| \text{tachyon} \right> = \tilde{L}_n \left| \text{tachyon} \right> = 0, \quad n > 0; $$
$$ L_0 \left| \text{tachyon} \right> = \tilde{L}_0 \left| \text{tachyon} \right> = a \left| \text{tachyon} \right>. $$

Based on these assumptions he identifies the vertex operator with

$$ V = \int d^2 \sigma \: \cdot \, : e^{i k \cdot X } :, $$

where $:...:$ denotes normal-ordering, radial-ordering is implicit and $k$ is on-shell with negative (tachyonic) $m^2$.

$V$ is conformal-invariant. As far as I understand, this can be showed on the quantum level by evaluating the $VT$ OPE (or, equivalently, by evaluating the residues of $VL_n$, where $L_n$ are the Virasoro generators).

I am trying to understand why this is a valid choice. Specifically, it would be great to make sense of this in terms of path integrals of functionals.

It is well known that observables of a quantum theory are expectation values (path integrals weighted by the classical action) of gauge-invariant functionals. These expectations can be evaluated using the Faddeev-Popov procedure which fixes the gauge and ensures that expectations weighted by the new action are correct, but **only** if the functional of interest is gauge-invariant.

This point of view makes a lot of sense in QFT.

Different ways to fix the gauge exist. These give rise to different actions and (in general) different expectation values. Since the choice of gauge-fixing is arbitrary, only gauge-invariant expectations (which coincide) make sense as physical observables.

Now back to the tachyon vertex operator. I would expect it to correspond to some (classical) gauge-invariant functional over $X^{\mu}$ and the world-sheet metric $g_{\alpha \beta}$.

Such a functional has to be an integral with a diffeomorphism-invariant measure:

$$ \sim \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g}. $$

Then there are Weyl transformation. In order to be Weyl-invariant, this integral has to have an inverse world-sheet metric which cancels the square root of the determinant in two dimensions:

$$ \sim \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g} g^{\alpha \beta} $$

The last formula contains loose indices which (again, diffeomorphism-invariance) have to be contracted with something. For example,

$$ \sim \int d^2 \sigma \sqrt{g} g^{\alpha \beta} \partial_{\alpha} X^{\mu} \partial_{\beta} X^{\nu} e^{i p \cdot X }, $$

which looks much like the graviton insertion operator.

On the contrary, it can be shown that the tachyon vertex operator is conformal-invariant in some weird quantum sense, by taking its residue with the $L_n$ conformal generator (or just with $T$).

But what about diffeomorphism- and Weyl- invariance, separately? $L_n$s don't generate them. One could expect that, for example, products of $V$ (which correspond to tachyon scattering amplitudes) have different expectations when evaluated on different world-sheet backgrounds related by diffeomorphisms and/or Weyl transformations. Because, again, Faddeev-Popov method gives different expectations of a non-gauge-invariant functional when different gauge-fixings are used.

**My question is: what happened to $\sqrt{g}$ and $g^{\alpha \beta}$ in the tachyon vertex operator; why is it considered diffeomorphism- and Weyl- invariant? And is it even possible to represent the Virasoro-Shapiro amplitude, for example, in terms of the expectation of some classical diffeo- and Weyl- invariant functional?**

Comment: As a lazy answer to your first question, not going back to my string theory textbook, I think the factors of $\sqrt{g}$ and $g^{\alpha\beta}$ are missing because he's working in the conformal gauge. In this gauge the metric on the worldsheet is the familiar $ds^2 = dz d\bar{z}$. In a more general gauge they would be present.

Comment: @lurscher, please explain yourself.

Comment: @SurgicalCommander I see. But your proposition is based on the fact that there is an diffeo- and Weyl- invariant generalization of the insertion operator. Could you provide one?

Comment: @lurscher I was told many times and have seen in different papers that diffeomorphisms are gauge symmetries of the bosonic string. What do you mean by 'not a gauge group of GR'? Why GR, and why are they not even a gauge group of GR?

Comment: I don't have one, in all treatments I've seen, the gauge is first fixed and then these expressions are written down. But the vertex operator exists regardless of which gauge you choose to work in. So I'm sure it exists although I don't recall ever seeing it worked out (that could well be due to my faulty memory). Hence the lazy answer :) And I disagree with lurscher, it's widely known that diffeos are a gauge symmetry, unless of course you choose an unnecessarily restrictive definition of gauge symmetry for the sole purpose of arguments like this.

Comment: Also, having thought about it a second time, I think you want to study the BRST formulation--in this formulation the gauge is not fixed, so that the gauge symmetries are manifestly preserved, and instead one projects out un-physical states. Polchinski vol. 2 is good for this, look up vertex operator in the index and in many of the places it appears it does so in an un-gauge fixed way. This might lead you to your answer.

Comment: @SurgicalCommander, BRST is a whole different subject on which I will soon post many questions here :) I don't understand how the symmetry is preserved since BRST naturally relies on the Faddeev-Popov trick where a gauge-fixing term is introduced.

Comment: @Hindsight, here is a pretty good exposition of the argument: http://www.mth.kcl.ac.uk/~streater/lostcauses.html#XXII

Comment: @lurscher and how do you suppose it should to help me?